# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found (webserver -> error, locahost -> all good)

Tags: php

I am getting error

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'MyClass' not found in /home/x/domain.com/x/x/init.php:3 Stack trace: #0 /home/x/domain.com/x/login.php(6): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /home/x/domain.com/x/x/init.php on line 3
```

The thing is, I can run it in XAMPP on localhost without problems, I even ran it on the webserver before. The only thing I did is: deleted DB & files from webserver and 1:1 copied from XAMPP to the webserver and by that moment, I am getting this error.

I have edited things like DB connection etc, there is no error at all ** I THINK ** (since it is running fine in the XAMPP, PHP version is same on webserver as XAMPP (7.3)).

Webserver is running on Namecheap, it is shared hosting, so it is Litespeed server

mainfolder/index.php which is redirecting to login.php (mainfolder/clients/login.php) & login is calling init.php which is in clients/iip/init.php. require_once 'iip/init.php'; (i tried even './iip/init.php') and that 'user' class is located in iip/functions.php called from iip/init.php ( require_once 'functions.php'; )

**EDIT: I tried to access init.php at the working XAMPP side and i am getting the same error, BUT site is still working, i am confused**

Comment: Please show us the file/folder structure of the mentioned files (init.php and login.php) and how you're trying to require them. It looks like a path issue`domain.com/x/x/init.php` unless you have a folder named `x` inside another folder named `x`. But it's pretty impossible for us to know what actually happens with virtually no information.

Comment: files: main folder/index.php which s redirecting to login.php (main folder/clients/login.php) & login is calling init.php which is in client/iip/init.php.

require_once 'iip/init.php'; (i tried even './iip/init.php')

and that 'user' class is called from init.php with require_once 'functions.php';

Comment: Please add all necessary details [to your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68696684/edit) (like a proper directory tree and copy/paste the relevant code) instead of in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you specified your `DocumentRoot` (in apache config file) correctly?
It seems that your web server can't find specified file or `MyClass` is not defined in specified file.

Comment: login.php -> require_once 'x/init.php';

the class is 100% fine and right there in init.php, do not really understand what is the problem since it is running fine or XAMPP && other files which does not require init.php are working aswell (on the webserver)

Comment: use: require_once './x/init.php';

Comment: getting same result

Comment: I think you have problem with the paths of files. Search some about relative and absolute paths.

Comment: if I understand correctly, the webserver found init.php but "can't see" the "user class"

Comment: Can you give a structure of your project? What is your `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: put a `die("Check")` or something in `init.php` to confirm that your web server can see it.

Comment: And for sure, restart your XAMPP. I think you may changed your cofig file without restarting your web server.

Comment: Yeah, as I though, respose: Check

Comment: Do the other stuffs and let me know

Comment: Still same, broken on webserver (hosting) side and running perfectly at XAMPP.

Comment: On web server you shouldn't the same path as local! You should edit your path on the web server. I'm sure that the problem is with your paths.

Comment: What is the problem with having 1:1 paths at local / hosting? Since the files are still same, just different webserver (it is like MAINFOLDER and there is index.php which is redirecting to next folder, there should not be problem with having same paths as local)

Comment: Read about relative and absolute paths. I think you can solve all of such errors by understanding the relative and absolute paths.

Comment: The thing I am saying is, few hours ago the paths were still same (on local & hosting) and it was running pretty fine so..

Answer (score 0):

You are probably making a mistake specifying the file path. The file path could be like "localhost/functions.php".

Also, after uploading the files to the server, are you sure that you can make the database connection without any problems?

Comment: The path should be fine, since i ran this same copy (with same directions before)

yeah, DB connection is fine

Comment: `The file path could be like "localhost/functions.php"` Why should it be `localhost/functions.php` on the web server? The OP says that it works on localhost but not on the web server. And it's a require that throws the error, so not sure why the host name (like `localhost`) should be involved at all? It's very unclear what you mean in your answer.